# Does separate method by argument?

Tags: python, function, methods, architecture

Could you give me an opinion which A or B is better?

I sometimes get lost in the definition of method.

```py
# Both returns same value.
# Only the arguments are difference.


# ------------------
# pattern A
def some_method_by_name(name: str):
    record = <SELECT ... WHERE record_name=str>
    return record

def some_method_by_id(id: int):
    record = <SELECT ... WHERE record_id=id>
    return record


# ------------------
# pattern B
def some_method(**kwargs):
    if 'id' in kwargs:
        record = <SELECT ... WHERE record_id=kwargs.get('id')>
    elif 'str' in kwargs:
        record = <SELECT ... WHERE record_name=kwargs.get('str')>
    else:
        raise Exception('wrong!')
    return record
```

I think that 'A' is good because to separate method by arguments is easy to understand, but I think that it is verbose.

Thanks.

Comment: Using 'str' as a key is not really a good idea as `str` is a reserved keyword. For pattern B, your code should look for keys in `kwargs` so 'str' can be replaced by `record_name`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @wwii Oh, sorry. Thank you for your attention.